# Hibernate UUID vs String behavior - similar IDs load as same entity and second entity is ignored/overwritten - collision

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, uuid

recently a colleague changed a ID type from `String` to UUID in our class, see below:

### Original

```
public class EventEntry {
    
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    //@Column(columnDefinition = "RAWUUID RAW(16)")
    String id;
```

### Modified

```
public class EventEntry {
    
    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
//    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    //@Column(columnDefinition = "RAWUUID RAW(16)")
    private UUID id;
```

We are seeing some changes in the behavior now, specifically 2 changes.

The first is that the IDs in the database have changed from e.g.
`a656944f-0b1f-4b0e-b3d6-cfc22c64e282` to
`2166942B104D4846A2EAFEE7BC4C8866`

The second change involved IDs that are very similar. We had done some manual edits/insertions and had 2 events with very similar IDs:

`bad5b19f-479c-4a99-a814-306e7289ea53` vs
`bad5b19f-479c-4a99-a814-306e7289ea54`

Our JPA query is now loading these 2 rows as the same entity, specifically the one with `bad5b19f-479c-4a99-a814-306e7289ea54` . There seems to be some sort of collision - and I suspect it's because the manually inserted one is very similar to the original and is not following a valid UUID algorithm.

Can someone confirm this and explain the mechanism behind this? Why would the system silently fail and basically treat 2 rows with a very similar UUID as the same row... (it's completely ignoring the information inside the actual second row inside the db) ?

Comment: Does `generator = "uuid2"` mean that a [version 2 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_2_(date-time_and_MAC_address,_DCE_security_version)) will be generated? If so, you might want to look into that...

Comment: The first change is obvious as the new `UUID` type has a different string representation. In teh secodn problem is interesting that you use the original `String` format, should't you use the new one? Also the *comments* in the old and new class needs probably a review. Do you have problem with *migrated* rows or with new rows inserted after the change?

Comment: Oracle [sys_guuid](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions202.htm#SQLRF06120) on some platforms produces *very similar* UUIDs differing only in few bits in the *middle* (not at the end as you observed). But this should only confuse the *eye*, not the Hibernate mapper;)